# Generic all purpose implementation for HttpPost, HttpGet, HttpPut, etc

Tags: java, generics, http-post

I created a method that loops around and gets a hold of an incoming request's headers and then transfers them to a HttpPost, HttpGet, etc object depending on what the request method was:

```
protected HttpPost savePostData(HttpPost httpPost, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = servletRequest.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {

    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
    Enumeration<String> headers = servletRequest.getHeaders(headerName);
    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
        httpPost.addHeader(headerName, headerValue);
    }
}
StringEntity requestBody = new StringEntity(servletRequest.getParameter(parameterBody));
httpPost.setEntity(requestBody);
return httpPost;
```

}

AND

```
protected HttpPut savePutData(HttpPut httpPut, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = servletRequest.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {

    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
    Enumeration<String> headers = servletRequest.getHeaders(headerName);
    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
        httpPut.addHeader(headerName, headerValue);
    }
}
StringEntity requestBody = new StringEntity(servletRequest.getParameter(parameterBody));
httpPut.setEntity(requestBody);
return httpPut;
```

}

But I do not want to repeat code, and I do not know how to make a token that could serve as a universal argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for example HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase - this class is right above HttpPut and HttpPost in the inheritance tree. As I can see you are only using addHeader() and setEntity() methods, the class I mentioned also 'has' them.

Direct link to doc: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html

Comment: That seems useful. How exactly can I go about doing this? Should I cast when returning HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase to the desired object type?

Comment: Know that it's old question but to find complite solution take a time... so, who those who faced with this - use "HttpRequestBase" instead of "HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase "